# Is ask.debian.net using StackExchange engine?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Is the http://ask.debian.net/ website using the StackExchange's engine? Is it considered part of the SE network?

Comment: ...no. It doesn't even *look* like a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: It uses http://shapado.com/

Comment: @TheEstablishment [stackoverflow-like app written in ruby](http://gitorious.org/shapado)

Comment: Then why did you ask the question?

Comment: @TheEstablishment I noticed it after I posted the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web applications inspired by Stack Exchange's system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/web-applications-inspired-by-stack-exchanges-system)

Comment: How TF is this not a relevant question? I've been searching for an Ask Debian, and I found this answer. Luckily there is one relevant answer before some zealots managed to close and "off-topic" the question. I swear, some of the most useful answers on SE (another example: best library / framework / language categories) come in answers to closed questions. You should care more about useful results than ideological purity, zealots (then again, you would be normals not zealots if you did). We should really track the zealots who do this and see their statistics.

Comment: @dan3. It's Ask Debian. You know, Debian, the bastion of ideological purity. *Of course* it's not using Stack Exchange.

Comment: Btw, you’re supposed to ask “Debian-questions” on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is someone running around slapping people with a splintered ruler? I guess in the minds of some there are magical "no question" zones and other various and rigidly inflexible ways to 'handle' 'those people' that seek to elevate their understanding.

Answer (score 10):

No, I don't think so. It has the following text at the bottom of that website:

> All Shapado.com content and data are available under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license. Powered by Shapado 4.0.1 under the GNU Affero General Public License

It doesn't look anywhere close to a StackExchange site.